# Extending DOMWindow object

Tags: javascript

I'm a total JavaScript/jQuery n00b, so please forgive me in advance.

Imagine there's a webpage (`W1`) which displays a list of items (`I1`, `I2`, ...). Now there's a second webpage `W2` which displays `W1` in a FancyBox'ed `iframe` (`<a class="iframe" href="addressof(W1)">Pick items</a>`).

Each item inside a `W1` has a JavaScript handler attached to its `click` event, which does this:

```
function SetOpenerClient(id, name,isHoldings)
{
    var _hfBackPath = document.getElementById('ctl00_main_hfBackPath');
    var url = _hfBackPath.value;
    window.navigate(url +"?id="+id+"&name="+name+"&isHol="+isHoldings);
}
```

The usual way this whole mess is used is by `window.open()`ing a window and providing a "backpath":

```
window.open(addressof(W1) + "?backpath=" + addressOfHandlerThisWebSite, 
    "selectClient", 
    "status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes")
```

Now here's whay my investigations show. Whenever a user click on an item inside of `W1`, it niavigates back to `backpath` (`_hfBackPath` from `SetOpenerClient()`), which happens to be a specially crafted page which grabs `id` querystring parameter, stuffs it inside a `Session` and does all kinds of other stuff.

When `W1` gets opened inside an `iframe`, Chrome complains:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'navigate'

Here's whay I want (by the way, there's $50 bill glued under your chair) and I really hope this is possible. I want to "redefine" `window.navigate` method to so that I could handle item selection manually. Is this possible? My naive attempts of setting

```
DOMWindow.navigate = function () { alert("window.navigate"); };
```

apparently don't do anything.

Comment: Do you mean something as simple as `window.navigate = function () { alert("window.navigate"); };`?

Comment: @Matt For starters I'd just like to intercept a call to `window.navigate` **inside** the `iframe` that FancyBox opened for me.

Comment: @AntonGogolev: If the `iframe` is opening a document on a different domain, you've got no change due to X-domain policy. If thats not the case, you need to get a handle on the `iframe` element, and try; `yourIframe.contentWindow.navigate = function () { window.parent.whatever; }`

Comment: @Matt It is indeed on a different domain. Is `crossdomain.xml` with `allow-access-from domain="*"` the correct way of thinking?